# I'm getting the following error on my android gradle sync > No signature of method: build_4qx06ffutezna4.android() is applicable for argument types:

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm getting this error even after changing many factors in build.gradle. Please suggest me the changes to get the success in gradle sync. If anyone needs more information, please let me know

```
// Apply the necessary plugins for building an Android app and using Kotlin.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

// Load the keystore properties from a file if it exists.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    println('key store exists = = ' + keystorePropertiesFile.exists())
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

// Configure the Android-specific build settings.
android {
    //ndkVersion = "21.3.6528147"
/*
    splits {
        density {
            enable true
            reset()
//           include "mdpi"
            include "xhdpi"
        }
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            //include "armeabi-v7a"
            //include "arm64-v8a"
            include "arm64-v8a"
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'

            universalApk true
        }
    }
*/

/*
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
*/


/*
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
*/
/*
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }*/

    kotlinOptions {         jvmTarget = '1.8' }
    compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.android.new'
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 20
        versionName 'V1.0.0.19'

        // Use vector drawables with the support library and set the source sets.
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        sourceSets.main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = []
            resConfigs 'en'
        }
        ndk {
//            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi", "x86", "x86_64"
        }

        // Define static BuildConfig variables.
        buildConfigField('int', 'NOVA_DB_VERSION', '${rootProject.ext.config.NOVA_DB_VERSION}')
        buildConfigField('int', 'USAGE_DB_VERSION', '${rootProject.ext.config.USAGE_DB_VERSION}')
        buildConfigField('int', 'REPORT_DB_VERSION', '${rootProject.ext.config.REPORT_DB_VERSION}')
        buildConfigField('String', 'REPORT_SERVER_IP', '\'${rootProject.ext.config.REPORT_SERVER_IP}\'')
        buildConfigField('String', 'EDUPAL_STUDENT_SERVER_IP', '\'${rootProject.ext.config.EDUPAL_STUDENT_SERVER_IP}\'')

        // Configure the signing for release builds.
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                v1SigningEnabled true
                v2SigningEnabled true
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }

        // Configure the build types, including resource shrinking, code obfuscation, and signing.
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources false
                //minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), "proguard-rules.pro"
                debuggable false
                jniDebuggable false
                renderscriptDebuggable false
                pseudoLocalesEnabled false

                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
            staging {
                // Specifies a sorted list of fallback build types that the
                // plugin should try to use when a dependency does not include a
                // "staging" build type. You may specify as many fallbacks as you
                // like, and the plugin selects the first build type that's
                // available in the dependency.
                matchingFallbacks = ['release']
            }
            debug {
                /* minifyEnabled true
                 shrinkResources true
                 debuggable true
                 jniDebuggable true*/
            }
        }

        // Exclude certain files from the APK packaging.
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        }

        // Set the Java source and target compatibility to 1.8.
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }


    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
        /*implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.10.0'*/
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        // implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
        implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
        implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'
        //implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.6.0'

        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.10'
        implementation 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.4.0'

        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'

        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
        /*
        implementation files('libs/jWebSocketClientAPI-1.0.jar')
        implementation files('libs/jWebSocketCommon-1.0.jar')
        implementation files('libs/jWebSocketJavaSEClient-1.0.jar')
        *///retrofit
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.2'
        implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1'
        testImplementation 'androidx.work:work-testing:2.8.1'
        implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'

        //implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0-rc01'
        implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1'
        kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1'
    }
}
```

I need the gradle sync need to success, I have changed the ndkfilter, proguard rules and typo error and structure but nothing helps me to get complete gradle sync.